# Get clicked Tile details in FLP Plugin

Tags: plugins, sapui5

I have developed a FLP plugin, which captures some activities by user in FLP. It works fine as expected. User will be having many tiles in FLP, which can be custom time, standard Fiori app tile, etc..

Now my requirement is: Capture information about the tile clicked by user. For example, if user clicks a tile with Text "Create PO", I should get the tile text in my FLP plugin runtime.

I could not find anything related to this from an FLP plugin perspective. Can someone please help me on how to achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Register appOpened event of Fiori Launchpad in onInit (say _appOpened).
Now in the event handler, oParam3.text gives you the data which you are looking for..

```
 _appOpened: function (sParam1, sParam2, oParam3, oParam4) {
    var sClickedTileName = oParam3.text;
    }
```

Cheers,

FH

Comment: Worked like a charm. I don't see any documentation on these things!!
Thanks a lot for this info..